# What's the use of `MutableTransitionState`? Looks like mutableStateOf does all it can equally good

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation, it is mentioned that

We sometimes want to have an initial state different from the first target state. We can use `updateTransition` with `MutableTransitionState` to achieve this. For example, it allows us to start animation as soon as the code enters composition.

```
// Start in collapsed state and immediately animate to expanded
var currentState = remember { MutableTransitionState(BoxState.Collapsed) }
currentState.targetState = BoxState.Expanded
val transition = updateTransition(currentState)
// ...
```

(**For full code, refer to full code example 1. below**)

However, the above code is only working for initial animation but not subsequent (i.e. change from `Expanded` to `Collapsed`), as whenever the `currentState.targetState` changes, the composable function will run and retriggered `currentState.targetState = BoxState.Expanded`.

To fix the problem, I'll have to

```
    var currentState by remember { mutableStateOf(BoxState.Collapsed) }
    val transition = updateTransition(currentState, label = "")

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        currentState.targetState = BoxState.Expanded
    }
```

(**For full code, refer to full code example 2. below**)

This will make the animation start automatically from `Collapsed` to `Expanded`. Also subsequently upon change from `Expanded` to `Collapse` (e.g. through a button click), it will still work, as the `LaunchedEffect` is no longer triggered.

With the `LaunchedEffect`, we can also do it with normal `mutableStateOf`, i.e. without `MutableTransitionState`, and still, behave well.

```
    var currentState by remember { mutableStateOf(BoxState.Collapsed) }
    val transition = updateTransition(currentState, label = "")

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        currentState = BoxState.Expanded
    }
```

(**For full code, refer to full code example 3. below**)

So I cannot see any extra benefit using `MutableTransitionState` compare to the normal `mutableStateOf`. Anything I miss?

## Full Code that describes the situation above

### 1. MutableTransitionState code follow document example that doesn't work

The code that doesn't works with just `MutableTransitionState` (i.e. no effect on button click, only having initial animation)

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    val currentState = remember { MutableTransitionState(BoxState.Collapsed) }
    currentState.targetState = BoxState.Expanded
    val transition = updateTransition(currentState, label = "")

    val rect by transition.animateRect(label = "") { state ->
        when (state) {
            BoxState.Collapsed -> Rect(0f, 0f, 100f, 100f)
            BoxState.Expanded -> Rect(100f, 100f, 300f, 300f)
        }
    }

    Column {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(500.dp)
                .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Green))
        ) {
            drawPath(Path().apply { addRect(rect) }, Color.Red)
        }
        Button(onClick = {
            currentState.targetState =
                if (currentState.targetState == BoxState.Expanded) BoxState.Collapsed
                else BoxState.Expanded
        }) {
            Text("Click Me")
        }
    }
}
```

### 2. MutableTransitionState code with launched effect that works

The code that works with just `MutableTransitionState` (i.e. have effect on button click, and having initial animation)

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    val currentState = remember { MutableTransitionState(BoxState.Collapsed) }
    val transition = updateTransition(currentState, label = "")

    val rect by transition.animateRect(label = "") { state ->
        when (state) {
            BoxState.Collapsed -> Rect(0f, 0f, 100f, 100f)
            BoxState.Expanded -> Rect(100f, 100f, 300f, 300f)
        }
    }

    Column {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(500.dp)
                .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Green))
        ) {
            drawPath(Path().apply { addRect(rect) }, Color.Red)
        }
        Button(onClick = {
            currentState.targetState =
                if (currentState.targetState == BoxState.Expanded) BoxState.Collapsed
                else BoxState.Expanded
        }) {
            Text("Click Me")
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        currentState.targetState = BoxState.Expanded
    }
}
```

### 3. Just mutableStateOf code with launched effect that still works

The code that works with just `mutableStateOf` (i.e. have effect on button click, and having initial animation)

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    var currentState by remember { mutableStateOf(BoxState.Collapsed) }
    val transition = updateTransition(currentState, label = "")

    val rect by transition.animateRect(label = "") { state ->
        when (state) {
            BoxState.Collapsed -> Rect(0f, 0f, 100f, 100f)
            BoxState.Expanded -> Rect(100f, 100f, 300f, 300f)
        }
    }

    Column {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(500.dp)
                .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Green))
        ) {
            drawPath(Path().apply { addRect(rect) }, Color.Red)
        }
        Button(onClick = {
            currentState =
                if (currentState == BoxState.Expanded) BoxState.Collapsed
                else BoxState.Expanded
        }) {
            Text("Click Me")
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        currentState = BoxState.Expanded
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MutableTransitionState` allows you to specify a different targetState than the initial state. Note it is not a `MutableState`.

If you do something like this:

```
    val currentState = remember {
        MutableTransitionState(BoxState.Collapsed).apply {targetState = BoxState.Expanded}
    }
```

You can expect the `Transition` to start an animation going from `BoxState.Collapsed` to `BoxState.Expanded` as soon as the `updateTransition` is composed for the first time.

`MutableTransitionState` is designed to 1) trigger animations when a composable gets added to the tree (i.e. enter animations), and 2) allow observation of currentState vs targetState through the `MutableTransitionState` object like this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/e6095adbb8ffba6aede464fd06ef7302eac61860/compose/animation/animation/integration-tests/animation-demos/src/main/java/androidx/compose/animation/demos/AnimatedVisiblilityLazyColumnDemo.kt#127